# how to log/check network traffic through my vpn service app in android

Tags: android, android-vpn-service

I have read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/vpn but i have a few questions about it:

1. am i creating a vpn client according to the code i have pasted below, if so, where is the vpn server?
2. My vpn service is working(as i can see it in the settings of the emulator), how do i know if the network traffic is flowing through my vpn service
3. how to log details of the network traffic?(destination adrress of the network request etc.)

Here is the code:-

```
public class vpnService extends VpnService {
public vpnService() {
}
private Thread mThread;
private ParcelFileDescriptor mInterface;
Builder builder=new Builder();
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mThread=new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                mInterface=builder.setSession("vpnService")
                        .addAddress("192.168.0.1",24)
                        .addDnsServer("8.8.8.8")
                        .addRoute("0.0.0.0",0).establish();

                FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(mInterface.getFileDescriptor());
                FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(mInterface.getFileDescriptor());
                DatagramChannel tunnel=DatagramChannel.open();
                tunnel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",8087));
                protect(tunnel.socket());

                while(true){
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
            }

            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                try{
                    if(mInterface!=null){
                        mInterface.close();
                        mInterface=null;
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){

                }
            }
        }
    },"vpnRunnable");
    mThread.start();
    return START_STICKY;

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if(mThread!=null){
        mThread.interrupt();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> am i creating a vpn client according to the code i have pasted below, if so, where is the vpn server?

No, you are just instructing Android to send the network packets of the device to your VpnService

> how do i know if the network traffic is flowing through my vpn service

You are currently not sending any data. To send data, you need to read IPv4 packets from the `in FileOutputStream` and write them to the tunnel channel

> how to log details of the network traffic

After you read a packet from the `in FileOutputStream`, you can the pcap4j library to parse the packet and then log it to the logcat console. For example:

```
IpV4Packet pkt = IpV4Packet.newPacket(buf, 0, len);
  Log.d("PKT", (String.format("[%s] %s -> %s [%d B]\n",
            hdr.getProtocol(),
            hdr.getSrcAddr().getHostAddress(), hdr.getDstAddr().getHostAddress(),
            pkt.length())))
```

You can see find a VPNService example [here](https://github.com/hihasan/VpnService/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/poc/vpnservice/service/Vpn.java)